# How to let combobox only stretch down in windows8

Tags: xaml, combobox, windows-8, controls

When I click Combobox to select a item, if I select the first one, the combobox will stretch down, but if I select the other item, the combobox will strech up and down, it will cover the content above the combobox. How to let it only stretch down, likes in winform?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially just rearrange the options so that whatever is selected is always moved to be the first option.